# How to avoid httpd.exe from creating etilqs in C\WINDOWS\TEMP\?

Tags: database, apache, sqlite, temp

I have Apache 2.4 installed in my computer and I use a localhost web application.

This application uses a sqlite database (through PHP PDO), which was small at the beginning but now it has 66518 rows.

For a while, when I run

```
SELECT Z.A,B,C,D,(SELECT 1 FROM X WHERE X.A=Z.A AND X.E IS NOT NULL)
FROM Y,Z
Where F=:f AND Y.A=Z.A
ORDER BY D IS NULL DESC, D IS "" ASC, D DESC
LIMIT :startRow,24
```

the COMODO Firewall's Defense+ Module warns me that `http.exe` wants to create the new file/folder `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\etilqs_???`, where ??? are random numbers and letters.

I think that it happens because the database has became big (at the beginning I didn't have this problem).

Is there a way to avoid these messages without changing httpd.exe's trustiness in COMODO Firewall, i.e., stop httpd.exe from creating these files/folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "Defense+" thingy did its job – it successfully defended your machine from the danger of doing something useful …

---

Seriously, SQLite has to create its temporary files somewhere, and the temporary directory is the directory that is designed to hold such files.

Your best way to solve this problem is to uninstall that Comodo thingy.

The second-best way would be to configure that so-called firewall to allow httpd.exe (and for that matter, all other programs) to access the temporary directory.

The least best way would be to configure the SQLite connection to try to store all temporary data in memory by executing [`PRAGMA temp_store = 2;`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_temp_store).
(This will undoubtedly blow up when your database becomes big enough so that the temporary data does not fit in memory.)

Comment: I have asked a spin-off of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122824/how-can-i-change-the-temp-folder-where-sqlite-creates-etilqs-files, maybe you could help me there too?