# How can I change the temp folder where sqlite creates etilqs files?

Tags: database, apache, sqlite, temp

(This question is a spin-off of [How to avoid httpd.exe from creating etilqs in C\WINDOWS\TEMP\?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121290/how-to-avoid-httpd-exe-from-creating-etilqs-in-c-windows-temp/16121977#16121977))

I have Apache 2.4 installed in my computer and I use a localhost web application.

This application uses a sqlite database (through PHP PDO), which was small at the beginning but now it has 66518 rows.

For a while, when I run

```
SELECT Z.A,B,C,D,(SELECT 1 FROM X WHERE X.A=Z.A AND X.E IS NOT NULL)
FROM Y,Z
Where F=:f AND Y.A=Z.A
ORDER BY D IS NULL DESC, D IS "" ASC, D DESC
LIMIT :startRow,24
```

the COMODO Firewall's Defense+ Module warns me that `http.exe` wants to create the new file/folder `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\etilqs_???`, where ??? are random numbers and letters.

I think that it happens because the database has became big (at the beginning I didn't have this problem).

COMODO Firewall shows the warning because `C:\WINDOWS` is a protected folder. Then, maybe I could change the folder so that sqlite stores these files in an unprotected one to avoid the warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the temp directory, change the value of the `TEMP` and `TMP` environment variables.

Depending on your Windows version, you are likely to find them under Computer ➝ Properties ➝ Advanced ➝ Environment Variables.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I already knew these environment variables but I didn't realize that sqlite is using them

Comment: It didn't work me somehow. The C drive is low on memory, but I couldn't get SQLite to store it's temp files on my D drive even though I changed environment variables. Am I missing something?

Comment: Environment variables are a per-process setting. You must restart the program using SQLite (and probably the program you're using to start that program).