# How can I change the temp folder where sqlite creates etilqs files on Ubuntu Linux R?

Tags: r, linux, sqlite, ubuntu, sqldf

I'm running sqldf in R on Ubuntu to select certain IDs from a big table with gigabytes of data and the process is creating temporary etilqs files under /var/tmp according to inotifywait monitoring file changes. However, my /var/tmp is on a small disk and this occasionally causes R to error out. I found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122824/how-can-i-change-the-temp-folder-where-sqlite-creates-etilqs-files) on how to change the temp folder location for sqlite on Windows, but I could not figure out how to make it work under Linux.

```
library(sqldf)
customer_extr <- sqldf("select b.*, a.year, a.name from product as b left join customer as a on a.ID = b.ID", dbname = "/home/userName/customer.db")
```

It seems to me that sqlite searches directories for temporary file storage locations (NOT the tempfile() that I can choose where to create the file by selecting tmpdir=) in the following order:

1. The directory set by PRAGMA temp_store_directory or by the sqlite3_temp_directory global variable
2. The SQLITE_TMPDIR environment variable
3. The TMPDIR environment variable
4. /var/tmp
5. /usr/tmp
6. /tmp
7. The current working directory (".")

I tried a few options but none of them seemed to work:

1. set temp_store_directory:

   ```
   con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("SQLite"), dbname = "/home/userName/customer.db")
   dbGetQuery(con, "PRAGMA temp_store_directory = '/mnt/tmp'")
   ```

   But this errors out:

   ```
   Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : basic_string::resize
   ```

   Currently, temp_store_directory is not set after checking

   ```
   Sys.getenv('temp_store_directory')
   ```
2. Before running R, I set the environmental variables to the desired temp folder: /mnt/tmp:

   ```
   export SQLITE_TMPDIR=/mnt/tmp
   export TMPDIR=/mnt/tmp
   ```

   I verified this has been successfully set up by

   ```
   echo $SQLITE_TMPDIR 
   echo $TMPDIR
   ```

   under Linux,

   ```
   Sys.getenv('SQLITE_TMPDIR') 
   Sys.getenv('TMPDIR')
   ```

   in R.

   However, my sqldf step still writes etilqs files to /var/tmp.
3. I tried to run

   ```
   dbGetQuery(con, "PRAGMA temp_store = 2")
   ```

   to instruct sqlite to save temporary files in memory. However, it's still writing etilqs files to /var/tmp.
4. I thought about creating a symbolic link for /var/tmp to point to /mnt/tmp but to do that I think I have to delete the folder /mnt/tmp first. This is not ideal since it's a shared Linux server and the disk for /mnt/tmp sometimes gets unmounted. I am not sure if this will cause any trouble for other applications and users.

I don't know how to check/change the sqlite3_temp_directory global variable in R.

This is my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
 [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] sqldf_0.4-10 RSQLite_1.1  gsubfn_0.6-6 proto_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] DBI_0.5-1     memoise_1.0.0 Rcpp_0.12.8   digest_0.6.10 chron_2.3-47
```

I can try upgrading my OS disk to a larger drive but isn't there a way to tell sqlite in R under Linux to write temporary files somewhere else? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: `basic_string::resize` is not an error message. `temp_store_directory` is not an environment variable; you would read it by executing the query `PRAGMA temp_store_directory`. Anyway, what is the actual directory you want to use? Can you access it from R?

Comment: I ran `PRAGMA temp_store_directory`, and it returns blank. But I can't set it to a different value(path). The actual directory I want to use is on a second hard drive /mnt/tmp. Yes R can access it. `basic_string::resize` occured and stopped R when the OS disk space ran out with a lot of temp files being created in /var/tmp by sqldf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get R to use a different temporary directory, it respects several settings of environment variables:

```
edd@max:~$ Rscript -e 'print(tempdir())'              # default
[1] "/tmp/RtmpUdPCFL"
edd@max:~$ TMPDIR="." Rscript -e 'print(tempdir())'   # overridden
[1] "./RtmpsJk2lP"
edd@max:~$
```

We will have to see with the sources of the RSQLite and/or sqldf packages to see if they use their own settings, or take it from R.  If it is the latter, as I suspect for at least sqldf then you have a way.

But do remember to set TMPDIR (or alike) *before* you start R.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I didn't know I need to put the variable in the same line of R. It did not work for me when I `export TMPDIR = .` first, then run `R`. For some unknown reason, `sqldf` still used `/var/tmp` to save the temporary files.

Comment: That is a shell convention. You can also set environment variables via files R reads at startup, see `help(Startup)`.