# Changing sqlite temp folder using RSQLite

Tags: sqlite, rsqlite

Using `RSQLite` in RStudio I run into the following error when running large queries

```
 Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
   database or disk is full
```

as the underlying process works on `/dev/xvda1`. I've got plenty of space on `/mnt/tmp`, but can't get `sqlite` to work on `/mnt/tmp`.

[How can I change the temp folder where sqlite creates etilqs files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122824/how-can-i-change-the-temp-folder-where-sqlite-creates-etilqs-files) points to a solution for Windows. I'm running RStudio on ubuntu.

I've copied the following in my `.profile` and `/etc/environment` (neither `~/.bash_profile` nor `~/.bash_login` are in my home dir.

```
 export TMPDIR=/mnt/tmp
 export TMP=/mnt/tmp
 export TEMP=/mnt/tmp
 export SQLITE_TMPDIR=/mnt/tmp
```

I've submitted the same env variable definitions at the command line, but still can't get `sqlite` to use `/mnt/tmp`.

Do I really have to recompile `sqlite` with `sqlite3_temp_directory` set to `/mnt/tmp`?

I have logged off between attempts...

Here's the content of `/etc/environment`. I've tried with and without `export`, with and without the quotes.

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
TMPDIR="/mnt/tmp"
TMP="/mnt/tmp"
TEMP="/mnt/tmp"
SQLITE_TMPDIR="/mnt/tmp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular slashes rather than backslashes, e.g., `export TMPDIR=/mnt/tmp`.
("\mnt\tmp" get expanded to "mnttmp" which probably doesn't exist.)

Comment: Good point, I did use the regular slashes, I'll correct the question.

Comment: In that case, my answer doesn't apply.  How are you determining that `/mnt/tmp` isn't being used?  And what does `pragma temp_store;` yield?

Comment: Oh, to address your doubts about the syntax, you *do* need the `export` to propagate environment variables, but it doesn't matter whether or not you use quotes in this instance (though if you wanted to use a directory with space in its name [virtually unknown under Unix/Linux, but common under Windows], then you *would* have to quote: `export SQLITE_TMPDIR="/mtp/temporary directory"`).

Comment: `pragma temp_store;` yields 0. `df -k` shows the root volume filling up as the query runs , while the /mnt/tmp (mounted volume) storage usage stays the same. Eventually I get the "database or disk is full" error.

Comment: I assume the database itself is on `/dev/xvda1`?  Are you running a large transaction?  What exactly is on `/dev/xvda1`?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to define the temporary environment variables in `Renviron.site` located in `$RHOME/etc`

My `RHOME` path is `/usr/lib/R`, which can be determined by calling `R.home()`.

This is what I added to `Renviron.site`:

```
 TMP=/mnt
 TMPDIR=/mnt
 TEMP=/mnt
 SQLITE_TMPDIR=/mnt
```

I'm still not 100% clear on how rstudio handles user environment variables, and how useful the Shell tool (within rstudio) is to establish env variable 'inheritance'. Anyway, using `Renviron.site` put my project back on the rails without having to agonise over recompiling sqlite with a new `sqlite3_temp_folder` global.